# How to preserve process/ ProcessBuilder object?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder, serializable

```
Process ps = new ProcessBuilder("iexplore.exe").start();
```

I am just calling this function and explore application opened. Here `ps.destroy();` is working into the same code but I want to kill this ps object from another java code. There is no concept of PID in Java 7 and I also used Serializable but no luck . is there any solution for this?

Comment: Hello there. Your problem is unclear. Could you please provide more information ? What do you mean *from another Java code* ? Does it mean *from another Java application* ?

Comment: Your title does not agree with your question. And what does [tag:serializable] have to do with it?

Comment: I have opened Internet Explorer using new processBuilder().start() . Now I want to close this Internet Explorer from another java application. Process class provides destroy() method through which I can close it. Therefore I want to maintain the state of same process object using serialization but Process class does not implement serializable interface. Is there any way to make this object serializable or Is there any other way to close this application?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`Process.pid()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#pid--) method available since Java 9:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("top").start();
long pid = p.pid();
```

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.ProcessImpl.pid() exception after using your snippets .

Comment: I am using JAVA 7 and JAVA 8.

Comment: @prithavirajnagar updated my answer, it's there from Java 9.